# Ajax with new controller action rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have created a new micropost controller action called more to receive ajax request.

```
def more
  micropost=Micropost.find_by(params[:id])
  @answers=micropost.answers
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html {redirect_to micropost}
   format.js
  end
end
```

and I have created jquery file- more.js.erb

```
$(".microposts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>"); `
```

to replace the content with a partial
my route file is like

```
resources :microposts, only: [:edit,:create,:destroy,:update,:show,:more] do
  member do
    get :more
  end
end
```

and i call the javascript file in the view with

`<%= link_to "load more",more_micropost_path(micropost),remote: true %>`

Its working with normal html request but not ajax.Nothing happens when I click on the link. I saw similar questions asked by some but the fixes are not working for me. Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance..
The error in firebug console is

`500 internal server error.
NoMethodError in MicropostsController#more. 
Undefined method id for nil:NilClass'

The firebug error console shows this jquery line on the right hand side. I am not sure if its an error.

lixhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Comment: what happens with ajax call.? please explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: Please clearly explain your issue and what errors are you getting?

Comment: nothing happens.. it just stays the same..

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: try this `$(".microposts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render paartial: 'users/unfollow') %>"); `

Comment: Are you monitoring the 'Network' tab in Chrome Dev Tools when you are clicking the link? You will see the request go red if there's an error and you can click the response to see the error.

Comment: 500 internal server error..NoMethodError in MicropostsController#more..undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass..This is the firebug console error I am getting.No error when I remove remote: true.

Answer (score 0):

judging by the error you posted in the comments, this line may be a problem:

```rb
micropost = Micropost.find_by(params[:id])
```

`find_by` requires a hash, so either use `find`

```rb
micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
```

or

```rb
micropost = Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: Changed the code as you said but the same error. And it works fine if I remove remote: true.

Comment: hmm, such an error should show in the local running server output. Can you paste error with a whole exception stacktrace?

Comment: I changed the jquery file to $("div").hide() and it works. Otherwise the firebug error console shows this jquery line on the right hand side. I am not sure if its an error. lixhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null ); The error on the console is added to the question above.